# Reusable, generic file collision handling

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, file-io

This is my first post here, but I've been lurking for awhile. I am developing a Python script that will process large amounts of data from an experiment. Files are read in, calculations are made, images are plotted and saved as .pngs, and calculated parameters are outputted to a .txt file.

When I save a file, the user is prompted if they want to overwrite any existing files. If yes, a file overwrite is attempted. If the file is locked/open in another program, a number is appended to the filename and then saved. If they do not want to overwrite, a number is appended to the filename. In order to not have redundant code, I wrote a generic "save" method:

```
def _handle_file_save(path, save, overwrite, *args):
    """
    Handles file collisions when saving files. If "overwrite" is true,
    overwrites file, if "overwrite" is false or the file to be overwritten
    is locked from editing, appends a number on end of filename to avoid
    file collision.

    Args:
        path (str): the path to the file to be saved
        save(): The save function used to save file
        overwrite (bool): true if user wants to overwrite file
        args: generic tuple of arguments used for different save functions

    """
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        if overwrite:
            try:
                print "Saving \"" + path + "\""
                save(path, args)
            # Signifies problem writing file (lack of permissions, open
            # in another program, etc.)
            except EnvironmentError:
                # save as incremented file number
                print "Whoops! Looks like %s is locked!" % path
                path = gen_alt_filename(path)
                save(path, args)
        else:
            # save as incremented file number
            path = gen_alt_filename(path)
            print "Saving as \"" + path + "\" instead"
            save(path, args)
    else:
        print "Saving \"" + path + "\""
        save(path, args)
    print "\n"
```

So I pass in a generic save function and any arguments that save function needs if any. Some file outputs don't require any arguments.

Flaws:

-Security risk? The client could pass in any arbitrary function as "save" and execute it.

-variable "args" gets passed to the save function reguardless of whether that method actually takes any args (i.e. args could be empty, but gets passed anyways

-doesn't check if appended filepath is also a locked/open file (could fix this with a while loop I suppose)

Possible improvements:

Use Python's functools.partial to reduce the function call's signature to one without "args" if args is empty

Alternative:

-Instead of passing a generic save function, I could replace "save(path, args)" with "new_file = open(path, 'w')" (i.e. test file write, if successful, return the path to that file and write there)

-Don't merge code, let every save method handle its own collisions seperately.

Nothing about any of this seems elegant. I'd greatly appreciate some advice on this, and how I can improve my coding strategies.

Comment: This might be more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review and delete your question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: How are you "locking" the file?

Answer (score 0):

To reply to some of your concerns:

> Security risk? The client could pass in any arbitrary function as "save" and execute it.

A client that is expected to pass a Python function to your function could also simply call `open()` on some path themselves, so your function won’t open new security “risks”. So I wouldn’t call it a risk btw. Users of libraries etc. are expected to use the library in a way that makes sense. It’s not your responsibility to secure everything.

> variable "args" gets passed to the save function reguardless of whether that method actually takes any args (i.e. args could be empty, but gets passed anyways)

You can solve that by unpacking `args` in the call again: `save(path, *args)`. That way, when `args` is empty, no additional argument will be passed. And also, the save fuction does not need to be a function that takes a path and a list of arguments but instead can be just a function that takes a path as its first argument.

> doesn't check if appended filepath is also a locked/open file (could fix this with a while loop I suppose)

Yes, I personally used a construct like this before:

```
baseFile, baseExt = 'someFile', 'txt' # these come from elsewhere
n = 1
while True:
    fileName = '{}_{:0>2}.{}'.format(baseFile, n, baseExt)
    if trySave(fileName):
        break
    n += 1
```